# Document uploaded to MS Teams using graph API gets corrupted

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to upload a document to Microsoft Teams using Microsoft Graph (beta version), but the document gets corrupted after a successful upload.

Using Graph, I'm first creating an Group, creating a Team based on the Group, adding some Team Members and finally uploading a document to the default channel.

All works fine except the uploaded document gets corrupted and the Office Online editor is not able to open it. We can however download the file and open in Microsoft Word after correcting the file.

Below is the code that I'm using for document upload->

```
FileInfo fileInfo = 
    new FileInfo(@"F:\Projects\TestProjects\MSTeamsSample\MSTeamsSample\Files\Test File.docx");

var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);
var endpoint = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{groupId}/drive/items/root:/General/{fileInfo.Name}:/content";

var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
fileContent.Headers.ContentType = 
    MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");

var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
requestContent.Add(fileContent, "File", fileInfo.Name);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, endpoint);
request.Headers.Authorization = 
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "<Access Token>");
request.Content = requestContent;
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

I tried changing content type to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` but no luck. I don't understand what could be wrong here. The code is pretty straight forward, based on the this [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_put_content). Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "We can however download the file and open in Microsoft Word after correcting the file"? What correction are you making?

Comment: After downloading the file from MS Teams, when you try to open it, MS word intimates you that the file is corrupted. It also says that word can try to correct the file and display the content. By doing this you will still be able to see the content of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
        var filePath = @"F:\Projects\TestProjects\MSTeamsSample\MSTeamsSample\Files\Test File.docx";
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var endpoint = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{groupId}/drive/items/root:/General/{fileName}:/content";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var content = new StreamContent(fileStream))
            {
                content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));

                // Construct the PUT message towards the webservice
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, endpoint))
                {
                    request.Content = content;

                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenResponse.Token);

                    // Request the response from the webservice
                    using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                    {
                        // Check the response.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am able to see Word document in Microsoft Teams editor.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for solution but I also wanted to understand how can we make it work with multi part file upload.