# Integrating AzureDevOps with MS Teams or OneNote in order to publish files into a designated thread

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams, onenote

I'd like to take advantage of MS Teams or OneNote to publish a html report from Azure DevOps release pipeline. I'd like to create a thread that the file will be published.

**Question:** Is there any task type in Azure DevOps that allows feeding a thread in MS Teams or OneNote with file content?

Comment: May I know how's the status of this? Free to comment below if you has any question:-)

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Because of most probable red tape regarding access to MS Teams I decided to use Azure Storage Account instead, because I have full control over it. Thank you for your input.

Comment: It's welcome. If possible, may I get learn with you that how do you make use of Azure storage account here? I think I should not the only one in stackoverflow. It would be much better, if you can share it as answer:-)

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I might be able to share the info about that on Monday morning.  If not I'll post answer this month.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks your time!! Looking forward to that:-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any task type in Azure DevOps that allows feeding a thread in
>   MS Teams or OneNote with file content?

If what you want is a direct task, I'm afraid to say, No, there hasn't such task or connector you can directly make use to upload file into `Teams`/`Onenote`.

But, the work around is integrate the corresponding [graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp) with `c#` and make service hook with azure devops pipeline.

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411592/document-uploaded-to-ms-teams-using-graph-api-gets-corrupted),

```
    var filePath = @"{file path}";
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var endpoint = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{groupId}/drive/items/root:/General/{fileName}:/content";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var content = new StreamContent(fileStream))
        {
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));

            // Construct the PUT message towards the webservice
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, endpoint))
            {
                request.Content = content;

                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenResponse.Token);

                // Request the response from the webservice
                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    // Check the response.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this needs you save the HTML file firstly. Only this, it can be detected and added by above c# script.